# How to convert HTML entities like &#8211; to their character equivalents?

Tags: php, character-encoding, special-characters

I am creating a file that is to be saved on a local user's computer (not rendered in a web browser).

I am currently using `html_entity_decode`, but this isn't converting characters like `&#8211;` (which is the n-dash) and was wondering what other function I should be using.

For example, when the file is imported into the software, instead of the ndash or just a - it shows up as `&#8211;`. I know I could use `str_replace`, but if it's happening with this character, it could happen with many others since the data is dynamic.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to define the target character set. `&#8211;` is not a valid character in the default ISO-8859-1 character set, so it's not decoded. Define UTF-8 as the output charset and it will decode:

```
echo html_entity_decode('&#8211;', ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

If at all possible, you should avoid HTML entities to begin with. I don't know where that encoded data comes from, but if you're storing it like this in the database or elsewhere, you're doing it wrong. Always store data UTF-8 encoded and only convert to HTML entities or otherwise escape for output when necessary.

Comment: Good call. I thought it was weird that the translation table output by `get_html_translation_table()` seemed to be missing `&ndash;` and `&mdash;`. But it hadn't occurred to me that it was because of the default output charset.

Comment: I'm using WordPress to store the data in the database.

Answer (score 17):

Try `mb_convert_encoding()`:

```
$string = "n&ndash;dash";
$output = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

```
function decode_characters($data)
{
    $text = $data;
    $enc = mb_detect_encoding($text, "UTF-8,ISO-8859-1");
    $resutl_characters = iconv($enc, "UTF-8", $text);
    return $resutl_characters;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Encode the file as UTF-8 using `utf8_encode()`. Then you don't have to replace/remove anything.

Comment: I tried adding charset=utf-8 to my header "header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');" and also ran the code that's echoed into the file using utf8_encode($data);, but it didn't make any difference. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to turn the characters into HTML Entities for storage and later retrieval?

```
htmlentities('–', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
// Returns "&ndash;"
```

If I have misread your question, please let me know.